# Appending a button on a div after div loads in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to access an div (or here a tr tag) on which i want to append a button . But i am unable to access  the tr tag because its loading after sometime and is not present in the DOM at that moment and getting error .

how to access a tag after loading something on the DOM

```
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnn');
    var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("scope")[0];
    tab.append(btn)
</script>
```

Comment: Continually check for its existence in a `setInterval`? (or `MutationObserver` if you wanted to be fancy)

Answer (score 2):

I think your document.getElementById code should only be executed after everyting has been loaded. You could add an "load" Eventlistener and put your code inside it.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnn');
    var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("scope")[0];
    tab.append(btn)
});
```

By the way: I always use "defer" for my  includes, like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/general/js/local.js') }}" defer></script>
```

This makes sure the "load" event will only be triggered after all includes have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could watch the DOM using the `MutationObserver` API. If the element you're observing is added, you could then apply your other code (e.g., append a button).

Basic Example:

```js
let watchDOM = (function(){
  let mo = window.MutationObserver;

  return function(obj, callback){
    if (!obj || !obj.nodeType === 1) {
  return;
 }  

    if (mo) {
      let obs = new mo(function(mutations, observer) {
          callback(mutations);
      });
      obs.observe(obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
    }
    
    else if (window.addEventListener){
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
    }
  }
})();

watchDOM(document.body, function(e) {
 // This will notify you if a new DIV is added.
 if (e[0].addedNodes[0].tagName === "DIV") {
   // If the DIV is added, you can then take some action here.
    // For example, you could append your button here.
   console.log("div added");
    }
});

// This adds a new DIV after 3 seconds of running the script
setTimeout(function() {
 let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this DIV getting created in the response of an AJAX call. If that is the case then you need to call you your button appending logic once the response of AJAX call has been received.

OR use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      // - Code to execute when all DOM content is loaded. 
      // - including fonts, images, etc.
  });
</script>
```

Comment: actually i am creating a pivot table using php   <div id ="itemlistid" style="display:none;"><?=(get_data('itemList'))?></div>
    <button id="btnn" " >Export
    </button> and the data is in itemList

Comment: I am not sure of the exact scenario, but give this a try as well.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      // YOUR CODE HERE
  });
</script>